# pgfplotstable multiple columns same heading name

Tags: pgfplotstable

I have some x y data that I wish to typeset using `pgfplotstable`, rather than having say 9 rows of 2 columns, I would like to have 3 rows, with 3 sets of xy pairs.

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mydata.dat}
    x y x y x y
    0 0 3 3 6 6
    1 1 4 4 7 7
    2 2 5 5 8 8
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableset{
        columns/x/.style={
             column name={$X$},
        },
        columns/y/.style={
              column name={$Y$},
              column type/.add={}{|}
        },
    }
    \pgfplotstableread{mydata.dat}\loadedtable
    \pgfplotstabletypeset{\loadedtable}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output:

[image: Output]

Clearly columns 2 to 6, in this MWE are not being typeset as desired. I am aware that this can be resolved by declaring unique column style for each column as follows:

```
\pgfplotstableset{
  columns/A/.style={
    column name={$X$},
  },
  columns/B/.style={
    column name={$Y$},
    column type/.add={}{|}
  },
  columns/C/.style={
   column name={$X$},
  },
  columns/D/.style={
    column name={$Y$},
    column type/.add={}{|}
  },
  columns/E/.style={
    column name={$X$},
  },
  columns/F/.style={
    column name={$Y$},
    column type/.add={}{|}
  },
}
```

Also slightly modifying the input data structure:

```
\begin{filecontents}{mydata.dat}
    A B C D E F
    0 0 3 3 6 6
    1 1 4 4 7 7
    2 2 5 5 8 8
\end{filecontents}
```

Producing the desired format, with column names [X Y X Y X Y]:

[image: Desired]

But I am trying to avoid having to effectively re-type the same code over and over. How can I use the same `pgfplotstableset` column style, for multiple columns in the same table.

Comment: So you want the title row to read `X Y X Y X Y`, correct?

Comment: Yes. Exactly...

Comment: @Jake, I have updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `every odd column` and `every even column` styles for this (noting that the column numbering starts at zero):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable,filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mydata.dat}
    x y x y x y
    0 0 3 3 6 6
    1 1 4 4 7 7
    2 2 5 5 8 8
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstableset{
        every even column/.style={
            column name={$X$}
        },
        every odd column/.style={
            column name={$Y$},
            column type/.add={}{|}
        }
    }
    \pgfplotstableread{mydata.dat}\loadedtable
    \pgfplotstabletypeset{\loadedtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: so what if there another number, say 4 or 5? unique columns, that repeat? This only works if there is 2.

Comment: @ADP: Good point. For rows, there's the `every nth row` style, but for columns, that's not implemented yet. Might be worth opening a feature request for that.